# How to skip masked values in bands?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

How to skip missing pixel values due they are masked? In the code below, empty lines with missing values in the spectral bands appear in the exported CSV file.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
        [[-77.10757333516824,34.93299957943245],
         [-77.05352362680463,35.141503960507634]]);

// Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
function maskL8sr(image) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var pixelsize = 30;
var data = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-03-01')
              .filterBounds(geometry)
              .map(maskL8sr)
              .getRegion(geometry, pixelsize);

var keys = ee.List(data.get(0));
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(data.slice(1).map(function(singleData){
  singleData = ee.List(singleData);
  var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, singleData);
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point([dict.get('longitude'), dict.get('latitude')]);
  return ee.Feature(point, dict);
}));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: featureCollection,
  description: 'CSV'
});
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/581c389fdb182843d143cf24818a7f4e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would probably be to just filter out features with null:

```
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(data.slice(1).map(function(singleData){
  singleData = ee.List(singleData);
  var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, singleData);
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point([dict.get('longitude'), dict.get('latitude')]);
  return ee.Feature(point, dict);
})).filterMetadata('B1', 'not_equals', null);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f54050614694b1f9f4406e4fae977bd4

Comment: There is also the `ee.Filter.notNull` filter, which is handy in this situation:
`.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(keys))`